# BLAS, Fortran and OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, lapack, blas

One of the core operations of my code is sum of N velocity fields, each one weighted by a gaussian random variable, into a single velocity field. In LaTeX notation it would be

U(x,y,z) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \phi_{n}(x,y,z) \xi_{n}

where \phi are the velocity fields and U is the result. I am currently considering different options of implementation to gain as much speed-up as possible, since my matrix can be really large: each field \phi has dimension (100,100,30), and they are in total 720.

I am currently investigating two ways of storing this data for an efficient use:

- The first has all the \phi fields piled one over the other, meaning in a single big matrix of dimension (100,100,30 * 720)
- The second is reshaping each \phi into a vector, and concatenate them to form a matrix of dimension (100 * 100 * 30,720)

The convenience of the second one is that once I have my random vector \xi, I can use BLAS `dgemv` to compute the matrix-vector product, and results show that the second option is more efficient.

However, since we are talking about a matrix of dimension (300.000,720), I thought that using OpenMp would bring a little benefit. I have set up a manual scheduling, where I divide the matrix into sub matrices, use private pointers to point at the portion of the matrix and call `dgemv` for each sub matrix. The result is that it takes more time than the original BLAS operation on the full matrix, even with 2 threads (which should not add too much communication overhead) so I am clearly missing some point here that I don't see.
I am compiling with a simple
`gfortran -o -02 main.out MWE.F90 -llapack -lblas -fopenmp`
and the code I am using is:

```
PROGRAM new_modes
   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: wp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307) 

   interface
      function OMP_get_wtime()
         INTEGER, PARAMETER :: wp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307)
         real(wp)           :: OMP_get_wtime
      end function OMP_get_wtime
  
      function OMP_get_thread_num()
         integer(kind = 4)  :: OMP_get_thread_num
      end function OMP_get_thread_num
   end interface

   INTEGER,    PARAMETER                              :: nn_tlu_nmod = 720
   INTEGER,    PARAMETER                              :: jpi = 100! 32
   INTEGER,    PARAMETER                              :: jpj = 100! 17
   INTEGER,    PARAMETER                              :: jpk = 30! 31
   INTEGER,    PARAMETER                              :: np = jpk * jpj * jpi
   !
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,          DIMENSION(:,:,:)   ::     A
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,  TARGET, DIMENSION(:,:)     ::     B
   REAL(wp),              POINTER, DIMENSION(:,:)     :: sub_B
   REAL(wp),              POINTER, DIMENSION(:)       :: sub_B_vec
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,          DIMENSION(:,:,:)   :: U_ref
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,          DIMENSION(:,:,:)   :: U
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,  TARGET, DIMENSION(:)       ::     vec_U
   REAL(wp),              POINTER, DIMENSION(:)       :: sub_vec_U
   REAL(wp), ALLOCATABLE,  TARGET, DIMENSION(:)       :: tcoeff
   REAL(wp),              POINTER, DIMENSION(:)       :: tcoef_pt
   !
   REAL(wp)                                           :: tic, toc
   INTEGER                                            :: ji, jj, jk, jm
   INTEGER                                            :: m_idx
   INTEGER                                            :: cnt
   !
   INTEGER                                            :: ierr
   !
   REAL(wp)      :: ddot
   !
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   !   Declaration for the Parallel parameters
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INTEGER, PARAMETER                       :: num_threads=1
   INTEGER, SAVE                            :: myID 
   !$OMP THREADPRIVATE(myID)
   !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   !   Declaration for the row scheduling
   !------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   INTEGER                                  :: sub_n
   INTEGER                                  :: istart,inext
   INTEGER,            ALLOCATABLE          :: work_sharing(:)

   WRITE(6,*) 'Number of threads employed in the solver:', num_threads 

   ALLOCATE(      A(jpi,jpj,jpk * nn_tlu_nmod), stat=ierr )
   ALLOCATE(      B(jpi*jpj*jpk,  nn_tlu_nmod), stat=ierr )
   ALLOCATE(     Bt( nn_tlu_nmod, jpi*jpj*jpk), stat=ierr )

   ALLOCATE( tcoeff(nn_tlu_nmod), stat=ierr ) 

   ALLOCATE(  U(jpi,jpj,jpk),            &
   &          U_ref(jpi,jpj,jpk),        &
   &          vec_U(jpi*jpj*jpk),  stat=ierr )

   cnt = 0
   DO jm = 1, nn_tlu_nmod
      !
      m_idx = ( jm - 1 ) * jpk 
      ! 
      DO jk = 1, jpk
         DO jj = 1, jpj
            DO ji = 1, jpi
               cnt =  cnt + 1
               A(ji,jj,m_idx + jk) = cnt * jm
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
       B(:,jm) = RESHAPE(A(:,:,m_idx + 1: m_idx + jpk), (/jpi*jpj*jpk/) )
      Bt(jm,:) = RESHAPE(A(:,:,m_idx + 1: m_idx + jpk), (/jpi*jpj*jpk/) )
   END DO
   tcoeff = 1._wp


   ! First option, normal matrix summation (already tested faster than
   ! with explicit do loop)
   tic = omp_get_wtime()
   U = 0._wp
   !
   DO jm = 1, nn_tlu_nmod
      ! Define zero-th indexed mode
      m_idx = ( jm - 1 ) * jpk 
      !
      U(:,:,:) = U(:,:,:) + A(:,:,m_idx + 1 : m_idx + jpk ) * tcoeff(jm)
      !
   ENDDO
   !
   toc = omp_get_wtime()
   print '("Time,   operation without for loops = ",f13.7," seconds.")', toc-tic
   U_ref = U

   ! Second option, exploit a different shape of the matrix in order to use BLAS
   ! (Usage of pointers speeds-up a lot)
   tic = omp_get_wtime()
   U = 0._wp
   sub_B => B(:, :)
   sub_n = np
   sub_vec_U => vec_U(:)
   tcoef_pt => tcoeff(:)
!  CALL DGEMV( trans,     m,           n, alpha,     A,   ldA,        x, incx,  beta,         y, incy )
   CALL DGEMV(   'n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, sub_B, sub_n, tcoef_pt,    1, 0._wp, sub_vec_U,    1 )
   U = RESHAPE(vec_U, (/ jpi, jpj, jpk /) )
   !
   toc = omp_get_wtime()
   print '("Time,           2D matrix with BLAS = ",f13.7," seconds.", f25.7)', toc-tic, MAXVAL(ABS(U-U_ref))



   ! Third option, Divide the job in a static way between M threads, use pointers to point at the 
   ! portion of the matrix assigned to each processor and use BLAS
   tic = omp_get_wtime()
   vec_U = 0._wp
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(istart, sub_n)
        myID = omp_get_thread_num()+1
      istart = work_sharing(myID)
       sub_n = work_sharing(myID+1)-istart
   !  CALL DGEMV( trans,     m,           n, alpha,           A, ldA,      x, incx,  beta,             y, incy )
      CALL DGEMV(   'n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, B(istart,1),  np, tcoeff,    1, 0._wp, vec_U(istart),    1 )
   !$OMP END PARALLEL  
   U = RESHAPE(vec_U, (/ jpi, jpj, jpk /) )
   toc = omp_get_wtime()
   print '("Time, Static scheduling BLAS OpenMP = ",f13.7," seconds.", f25.7)', toc-tic, MAXVAL(ABS(U-U_ref))


   ! Fourth option, run a parallel Do and use DDOT
   tic = omp_get_wtime()
   vec_U = 0._wp
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(ji)
   !$OMP DO SCHEDULE (STATIC)
      DO ji=1,np
   !        res = DDOT(           n,        x, inc_x,      y, inc_y )
      vec_U(ji) = DDOT( nn_tlu_nmod, B(ji, :),     1, tcoeff,     1 )
      END DO
   !$OMP END DO
   !$OMP END PARALLEL  
   U = RESHAPE(vec_U, (/ jpi, jpj, jpk /) )
   toc = omp_get_wtime()
   print '("Time,    Parallelized for loop DDOT = ",f13.7," seconds.", f25.7)', toc-tic, MAXVAL(ABS(U-U_ref))


   ! Fifth option, Divide the job in a static way between M threads, but using a transposed matrix
   tic = omp_get_wtime()
   vec_U = 0._wp
   !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(istart, sub_n)
        myID = omp_get_thread_num()+1
      istart = work_sharing(myID)
       sub_n = work_sharing(myID+1) - istart
   !  CALL DGEMV( trans,           m,     n, alpha,            A,         ldA,      x, incx,  beta,             y, incy )
      CALL DGEMV(   't', nn_tlu_nmod, sub_n, 1._wp, Bt(1,istart), nn_tlu_nmod, tcoeff,    1, 0._wp, vec_U(istart),    1 )
   !$OMP END PARALLEL  
   U = RESHAPE(vec_U, (/ jpi, jpj, jpk /) )
   toc = omp_get_wtime()
   print '("Time, Static scheduling tran OpenMP = ",f13.7," seconds.", f25.7)', toc-tic, MAXVAL(ABS(U-U_ref))


END PROGRAM
```

Thanks to all

**EDIT:**
I have modified the initial code with all the suggestions of [PierU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14778592/pieru), and added a fifth possibility, that basically transpose the matrix from the start (feasible in my case), in order to do a scheduling of contiguous memory positions. For some reasons this last one is anyway slower than the third one, which is counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: In the OpemMP solution you are passing non-contiguous arrays to DGEMV, thus implying a copy-in/copy-out behavior. Instead, you should pass the first element of each sub-array and play with LDA in the call to DGEMV

Comment: More precisely, instead of passing `sub_B` to dummy argument `A` you pass `B(istart,1)`, and instead of passing `sub_n` to dummy argument `LDA` you pass `np`. This assumes that `B` is a contiguous array (which it is in your code)

Comment: I have more comments: in your second option you really don't need the `B(:,:)` array, as `A(:,:,:)` can be passed instead. DGEMV() has no interface and therefore has no idea about the shape of the actual argument: you can pass any actual array, whatever the number of dimensions, and inside DGEMV() it is always seen as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Also, I don't get why you are using  pointers everywhere? For instance `sub_B => B(:,:)` is useless in your code, you can simply pass `B` to any routine instead of `sub_B`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the result does not change with ```      CALL DGEMV(   'n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, B(istart,1),    np, tcoef_pt,    1, 0._wp, sub_vec_U,    1 )``` and neither if I use ```vec_U(istart)```. Pointers are there to do the scheduling, if you say they are not needed I will take them away, thanks

Comment: Actually there may be a simple explanation (that I forgot): a matrix-vector multiplication is a memory-bound algorithm on usual computers. That is, the bottleneck is not the CPU load but the data transfer rate between the RAM and CPU. Memory-bound algorithms do not benefit from parallelisation, as whatever the number of available cores there is still a unique data transfer bus.

Comment: But in this last case, why with one thread is 10 times faster than with two? If the problem relies on the moving data I expect the time to be all the same regardless of the number of threads. In my case, 1 thread is 10 times faster than two.
(Is there a way to discuss this in private? without taking the comments as a chat)

Comment: It's OK to use the comments. 10 times slower with 2 threads looks indeed difficult to explain. Maybe the 2 threads compete for the memory access and generate many cache misses. Have you compared the runtimes with the code compiled without OpenMP and the code compiled with OpenMP and run with a single thread?

Comment: @Gilles it's OK, myID has a `threadprivate` directive at the beginning of the code*

Comment: So, I tried compiling and running your code on Linux. I compiled it with the Intel Fortran compiler. It runs OK on 1 thread but with more than 1 thread it crashes (segmentation violation) on the DGEMV() call. I don't know why... I then replaced `sub_B` by `B(istart,1)`in the arguments (and `sub_n` by `np` for the LDA argument), and not only it does no longer crash, but I do have a speed-up when using more threads (about 0.28" on 1 thread,  0.18" on 2 threads, 0,11" on 4 threads...)

Comment: Tried also with gfortran. Your original code is slower with 2 threads (3x slower), but is faster if I change the call to DGEMV() as above. You may have done something wrong when testing my suggestion.

Comment: May I ask you which compiler flags you used?

Comment: with gfortran (6.3.0) exactly the same as yours. And for Intel fortran (18.0.5): `ifort -O3 memobound.f90 -lblas -fopenmp -static -g`

Comment: And here is the modified call: `CALL DGEMV(   'n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, B(istart,1), np, tcoef_pt,    1, 0._wp, sub_vec_U,    1 )`. Among other details, your 4th solution misses the `tic` and the loop has not the right upper bound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248040/discussion-between-kimala-and-pieru).

Comment: @PierU "Memory-bound algorithms do not benefit from parallelisation" That is not true. CPUs can typically sustain 3/4 (or something thereabouts) of the requested total parallel bandwidth. So even with bandwidth-bound operations you should get good speedup, till something a little close to the total number of cores. People call this "bandwidth saturation".

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Well, it's not memory-bound, then...

Comment: @VictorEijkhout This is an interesting point, though. I remember a presentation about 8 years ago showing that on a typical quadcore CPU back then, a vector triad scheme (`d(i) = c(i) + a(i)*b(i)`, all doubles) had at most ~1.5x speed-up on 4 threads compared to 1 thread (and no improvement with more than 2 threads). This may have changed, as I can now observe a 3x speed-up on a more recent 8 (physical) cores CPU. Probably the bandwidth has progressed faster than single core performances during the recent years. For the record, on a 20 cores Xeon 6230 the maximum speed-up is ~6x.

Comment: @PierU I probably have pretty high-end CPUs: on 2x28 cores I still get 90 percent efficiency. Full efficiency at 40 or so. Code: https://bitbucket.org/VictorEijkhout/scientific-computing-public/src/master/code/hardware/

Answer (score 2):

In the third option (using `DGEMV` in a parallel region) the calls to `DGEMV` involve big non-contiguous sub-arrays, which trigger a copy-in/copy-out behavior. Replacing

```
    sub_B => B(istart:inext-1, :)
    ...
    CALL DGEMV('n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, sub_B      , sub_n, tcoef_pt,1, 0._wp,sub_vec_U,1 )
```

by

```
    ...
    CALL DGEMV('n', sub_n, nn_tlu_nmod, 1._wp, B(istart,i), np   , tcoef_pt,1, 0._wp,sub_vec_U,1 )
```

avoids the big copies and is much more efficient: with 2 threads I have timed a x1.6 speed-up instead of a 3x slow-down with the initial code.

Generally speaking it is always desirable to avoid the copy-in/copy-out behavior when possible, particularly when one deal with big arrays (the A and B arrays here occupy 1.6 GB each).

I do not repeat here the other comments I have made above about this code.

Comment: Note copy in/copy out will require a memory allocation, which could well be a serialisation point in an OpenMP code

Comment: Thank you very much for all your exhaustive answers. Can you point out to some reference to understand which procedures introduces copy-in/copy-out behaviour? I would not know how to understand if the array is going to be moved or not

Comment: I don't have a proper reference, but as a general rule: as soon as an actual argument is not contiguous in memory, the compiler generates a copy-in/copy-out... unless the dummy argument in the subroutine is declared with implicit shape (e.g. `real, intent(in) :: a(:,:)`). In the latter case the compiler is free to make a copy or not (it generally won't make a copy). A subroutine with implicit shape dummy arguments must be in a module or have an interface.